# Azure Devops Extension: What I should set in contribution section?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions

Creating an Azure Devops extension.

**My problem**

Trying to feed extension manifest file (vss-xtension.json) and the doc doesn't help me a lot to write **contributions** section.

I understand I set an item by deployed task. But what to set into **type** and **targets**?
Documentation is not clear for me.

This is the typical sample I can find:

```json
"contributions": [
    {
        "id": "DeployRG",
        "type": "ms.vss-distributed-task.task",
        "targets": [
            "ms.vss-distributed-task.tasks"
        ]
    }
]
```

**What I need**

What mean **ms.vss-distributed-task.task** and **ms.vss-distributed-task.tasks** ?
Is there other values?
Where is a documentation?

Thank you

Comment: You can get inspired by other well-known extensions with open source: https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-scanner-vsts/blob/master/extensions/sonarqube/vss-extension.json#L86

Comment: This is what I do. But I would like to understand. For the moment this is juste magic data for me